# Kernel Ip routing table is empty

Tags: networking, routing

Hello i am trying to connect to the internet on my DE10 nano board (running debian) via a ethernet cable that connected to my host pc. Currently, I am trying to find my default gateway ip with the command `route -ne` however it returns an empty table. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

`ifconfig` output:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::4c0:3fff:fe00:d85f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 06:c0:3f:00:d8:5f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 178  bytes 32996 (32.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47  bytes 12362 (12.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 39  base 0xe000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Current contents of /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: It seems like your device failed to obtain an IP address from your network DHCP. Fix that first and you should be good to go.

Comment: How do i fix that?

Comment: Is it a direct device-to-device connection?

Comment: @u1686_grawity i am connecting a ethernet cable from my host pc to my de10 board so that is can connect to the internet via the host, so i believe that would be called a  device-to-device connection

Comment: What OS is the host running? Was the host set up to provide DHCP?

Comment: host is windows 10,  i can see the ethernet connection in the control panel/network connections so i think it does have the capability

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, I am trying to find my default gateway ip with the command `route -ne` however it returns an empty table

It returns an empty table because you haven't *configured* a gateway yet. Your interface configuration says "use DHCP", but there's no DHCP server on the network, so there's no source that would provide the gateway address.

For the same reason, your routing table doesn't have the usual "subnet" routes because there's no IP address configured to derive the subnet routes from.

Either way, if you are currently configuring the host PC, you don't actually need to find out the default gateway's IP address, because according to your own description *the host PC itself* is supposed to be the gateway. So on the device, you need to specify the host PC's address as gateway – and on the PC, you need to specify nothing at all.

Comment: This was helpful. I also learned a bit from a tutorial i found, however i am still having some trouble. I made a new question with updated info: https://superuser.com/questions/1801053/ssh-timeout-with-ethernet-connection