# SSH timeout with ethernet connection

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet

Hello i am trying to connect to the internet on my DE10 nano board (running debian) via a ethernet cable that connected to my host pc (Windows 10). I followed a short tutorial on how to do this on a raspberry pi running Debian since its quite similar however i am having some trouble. Here is the link to the tutorial:
https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-connect-to-a-raspberry-pi-directly-with-an-ethernet-cable/

My issue is that i cant create an SSH connection from my host pc to my de10 board with ethernet, when i try to connect with the ip address the SSH Connection will time out.

Can anyone help me out with this? I have provided some info below that i think might be helpful.

The output of `ip a` on my de10 board:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:c0:3f:00:d8:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4c0:3fff:fe00:d85f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

From my HOST PC the ethernet adapter info is:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ea97:cab3:5d6d:fd4a%24
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.25.112
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

The the contents of /etc/resolv.conf :

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search localdomain linuxvmimages.local
nameserver 192.168.88.2
```

The command `route -ne` returns :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

The contents of /etc/network/interfaces.d :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.0.100  
gateway 192.168.0.1  
netmask 255.255.255.0  
network 192.168.0.0  
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.88.2
```

The contents of /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf :

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/sbin/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.33.137.250;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}

#interface eth0
#static ip_address=169.254.25.99
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.2


interface "eth0";
fixed-address 169.254.25.99;
option routers 192.168.0.1;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.88.2;
```

Comment: `Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.25.112` your HOST pc subnet is different from your potato pc subnet ... one doesn't know how to connect to the other

Comment: @JaromandaX hi, are you saying that the address value  /etc/network/interfaces.d should be the same as the IPv4 address 169.254.25.112 ?

Comment: no, I am saying one end of the connection is `169.254.25.112/24` and the other is not shown, though it may be `192.168.0.100/24`  - can't really say as you haven't actually shown what the IP address **actually is** ... but, the gateway on that device is `192.168.0.1` ... where is that gateway if the other end of the wire is `169.254.25.112/24`

Comment: @JaromandaX I should have mentioned that originally the  /etc/network/interfaces.d only had the first 7 lines in it, i added everything else so it may be incorrect including the gateway. Do you have an idea of how i could find out what the value should be for the gateway? Also is there a command i can use to show the ip address your looking for?

Comment: `ip a` is a good one

Comment: @JaromandaX i have updated the post with it

Comment: see, your dev board is `192.168.0.100/24` and it's connected to `169.254.25.112/16` ... they are different networks so they won't "talk" to each other

Comment: @JaromandaX So what changes do i have to make exactly? I'm a bit new to all this unfortunately

Comment: revert the settings you changed so the dev board gets IP address through DHCP, and connect the dev board to a router/switch?

Comment: Or, the above, but instead of connecting to router/switch, setup your windows to "share" internet with the ethernet port you mentioned `Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3` - or maybe bridge with whatever device your internet is available on

Comment: @JaromandaX ok so i reverted everything in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces.d` to default and now from `ip a` the `inet 192.168.0.100/24` has disappeared, i was able to bridge my wifi to my ethernet but with the disappearance of the ip address i am not sure what to use to ssh with

Comment: so, it's not getting an ip address? you do have some sort of DHCP server right (like, your main router for example) - perhaps you can set up a static IP address in the same subnet as your router now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure both devices to have IP addresses from the same network. As you currently have configured the DE10nano with `192.168.0.100/24`, you also need to configure the PC with an address from the same network (e.g. `192.168.0.7/24` will do).

The network prefix (or subnet mask) tells both hosts what addresses are local to the connection. As long as the PC has the auto-configured `169.254.x.x/16` address, it **does not know** that the DE10's 192.168.0.100 is available through that interface, nor does the DE10 know how to respond to the PC.

Comment: I am able to SSH into the board now via the ethernet cable but am still having issues connecting to the internet. i created a new post to show my new set up: https://superuser.com/questions/1801287/connecting-dev-board-to-internet-via-ethernet-cable-connection-to-host-pc

Answer (score 1):

So, the IP of your board is 192.168.0.100.

The host PC is 169.254.25.112. It is on a subnet /16. The IP of the board is not in the subnet of your host. Therefore, they do not communicate.

If you give your host an IP in the same subnet as your board, say 192.168.0.112 with a /24, you should be able to connect.